# Nested div doesn't overlap parent's siblings

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a **very** convoluted table in which I have to add a menu that appears on hover and has its position based on each row's position.
Every row is generated at the same time in a loop (React props.map), so changing the next row z-index is possible, but I don't know if I should.
I managed to do some work, but I can't seem to make the menu appear on top of the "th" other than its parent.

I know it (probably) has to do with the Stacking Context, but I don't know how to fix this.

This fiddle represents a very resumed version of the table: https://jsfiddle.net/4n9bj16x/2/

I tried a lot of things, and some worked but then it broke something else. What I need is a way of maintaining the first column fixed and make this menu overlap all "th" siblings.

Things that worked but broke something else:

- Taking the "sticky" position out of the "th", the menu will overlap perfectly, but then it break the fixed first column.
- Make the menu relative positioned, then it enters the normal flow, but that makes the div grow in and out.
- Remove the "th" background-color property, but then it becomes invisible and, when the table is scrolled, you can see all the other columns underneath.

Thanks in advance!

PS: The original table is coded in React and SCSS, if this is of any help.

HTML & CSS: (the fiddle is written in scss because its easier to read)

```css
.overflowTable {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 0;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
 table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
 tr {
  background-color: white;
}
 th {
  border-right: 2px solid #eee;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #333;
  left: 0;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: inherit;
}
 tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
 tbody th {
  cursor: pointer;
}
 tbody td {
  cursor: grab;
}
 tbody td:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
 .headerTable {
  font-family: "Open-sans", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #666;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
 .content {
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
 .content .actualMenu {
  visibility: hidden;
}
 .content .menuMore {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  visibility: hidden;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
 .content:hover .actualMenu, .content:hover .menuMore {
  visibility: visible;
}
 .content .title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
 .content .title .name {
  flex: 1;
}
 .content .title .moreOptions {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflowTable">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="headerTable">
          Name
        </th>
        <td class="headerTable">
          Status
        </td>
        <td class="headerTable">
           People
        </td>
        <td class="headerTable">
           Date
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="content">
        <div class="title">
          <div class="name">
            Name
          </div>
          <div class="moreOptions">
            <span class="actualMenu">...</span>
            <div class="menuMore">              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </th>
        <td class="content">
          Status
        </td>
        <td class="content">
          First Person
        </td>
        <td class="content">
          Random Date
        </td>
      </tr><tr>
        <th class="content">
        <div class="title">
          <div class="name">
            Name
          </div>
          <div class="moreOptions">
            <span class="actualMenu">...</span>
            <div class="menuMore">                   Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </th>
        <td class="content">
          Status
        </td>
        <td class="content">
          First Person
        </td>
        <td class="content">
          Random Date
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The hover menu (moreOptions) seems to ignore all z index positioning unless we turn off absolute.

Comment: Yes, if I take the "sticky" position out of the "th", the menu overlaps perfectly, but then it breaks the fixed first column. And if I make the menu relative positioned, it enters the normal flow, but that makes the div grow in and out. So what I need is this div off the normal flow and the first column fixed. But I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On hover change tr's and th's `z-index`

```css
.overflowTable {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 0;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
 table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
  tr {
 background-color: white;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
tr:hover {
  z-index: 2; 
   }
   tr:hover th {
  z-index: 3;
}

 th {
  border-right: 2px solid #eee;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #333;
  left: 0;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: inherit;
}
 tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
 tbody th {
  cursor: pointer;
}
 tbody td {
  cursor: grab;
}
 tbody td:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
 .headerTable {
  font-family: "Open-sans", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #666;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  min-width: 150px;
}

 .content {
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
 .content .actualMenu {
  visibility: hidden;
}
 .content .menuMore {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  visibility: hidden;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
 .content:hover .actualMenu, .content:hover .menuMore {
  visibility: visible;
}
 .content .title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
 .content .title .name {
  flex: 1;
}
 .content .title .moreOptions {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflowTable">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="headerTable">
          Name
        </th>
        <td class="headerTable">
          Status
        </td>
        <td class="headerTable">
           People
        </td>
        <td class="headerTable">
           Date
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="content">
        <div class="title">
          <div class="name">
            Name
          </div>
          <div class="moreOptions">
            <span class="actualMenu">...</span>
            <div class="menuMore">              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </th>
        <td class="content">
          Status
        </td>
        <td class="content">
          First Person
        </td>
        <td class="content">
          Random Date
        </td>
      </tr><tr>
        <th class="content">
        <div class="title">
          <div class="name">
            Name
          </div>
          <div class="moreOptions">
            <span class="actualMenu">...</span>
            <div class="menuMore">                   Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
              Options<br/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </th>
        <td class="content">
          Status
        </td>
        <td class="content">
          First Person
        </td>
        <td class="content">
          Random Date
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST ANSWER:**

You have to remove `background-color: inherit;` from `th`.

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp) resource:

> The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element.

**UPDATE:**

First of all, sorry for misunderstanding,

You gave `z-index: 2;` to `.content` class. Its mean all `.content` elements have equal index. You can fix this and add another way. Go second row and add `z-index: 3;` then you will understand me. :)

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jegm95L/1/)

```
<th class="content" style="z-index: 3!important;">
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I tried that already, but what it does is set the background color to transparent so, while the menu becomes visible, so does every other column when you scroll right!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I forgot to mention that every row is generated at the same time in a loop (React props.map), so changing the next row z-index may be possible, but I don't know how to do it recursively!

Comment: Then try z-index : auto; instead of specific index :) and don't forget vote me :)

Comment: Ok, I managed to solve the problem with your ideia, but I think there are better ways to do it still. I'll vote your answer!